# Reading binary data into a c# struct

Tags: c#, struct, binary-data

I have a file containing binary data with a format that matches this struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
    UInt32 count;
    UInt32[] items;
}
```

The binary data can be any length as there can be any number of items, but the number of items is defined in count. Using `Marshal.PtrToStructure` doesn't seem to allow for this binary format, where there is a variable number of items? Using Attributes you can set the size of the array of items, but this has to be a constant, is there no way to tell it to look in `count` while its reading the data?

I've thought of defining the format in XML, and using it to read into the struct with my own code, but this would be a lot of duplicate data, if the file format changed, I'd have to change the XML and struct, rather than just the struct.

And I've thought of using a custom Attribute on the `items` field, and writing my own code to read in the data but in order to enumerate through the struct's fields I'd have to use Reflection? which is slow?

(Also I could read it myself manually, but I've trimmed the struct down for the question, and like to not have to change the reading code if the structure changes)

Comment: I'm presuming you want to avoid XML due to its extra overhead (in parsing, and in filesize); parsing an XML file containing 10000 of these `MyStruct` can be done in a single line: 


    `List<MyStruct> data = (List<MyStruct>) new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyStruct>)).Deserialize(File.OpenText("MyStructs.xml"));`

Comment: The data is a preexisting binary file, I have no control how the data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Read()` method on an instance of `Stream`, reading into a `byte[]`, then use `System.BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytearray, startindex)` to get your binary data into `uint32` form.

Comment: I'm not having trouble reading the data, it's how I read the data in a way that reduces information duplication, isn't slow and doesn't require changes to the code that reads that data if the format changes.